# i devleop my app on heroku but link show me error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

2022-08-31T16:43:46.540417+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-08-31T16:43:46.540418+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-08-31T16:43:46.540418+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-08-31T16:43:46.540418+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
2022-08-31T16:43:46.540418+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-31T16:43:46.540418+00:00 app[web.1]: code: undefined
2022-08-31T16:43:46.540419+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-31T16:43:46.659118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-31T16:43:46.733053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-08-31T16:43:46.737622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-31T16:43:48.792424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`2022-08-31T16:43:50.536302+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is up and running on port 12850
2022-08-31T16:43:50.931734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-08-31T16:44:00.897054+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 701bf658 by user ansaripaniyara007@gmail.com
2022-08-31T16:44:00.897054+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user ansaripaniyara007@gmail.com
2022-08-31T16:44:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-31T16:44:01.359578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2022-08-31T16:44:01.365528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-08-31T16:44:02.716666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-08-31T16:44:02.882220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-08-31T16:44:03.449788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`2022-08-31T16:44:05.243481+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server is up and running on port 23280
2022-08-31T16:44:05.593505+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167282+00:00 app[web.1]: error connecting to db MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167295+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167296+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:10
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167297+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167297+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise ()
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167298+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167298+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1225:10)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167298+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:20)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167299+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/config/mongoose.js:2:10)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167299+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167299+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167300+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167300+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167300+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167300+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167300+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167301+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167301+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167301+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167301+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167302+00:00 app[web.1]: code: undefined
2022-08-31T16:44:35.167302+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168732+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/process/promises:279
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168733+00:00 app[web.1]: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168734+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168734+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168734+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168735+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168735+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:10
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168736+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168736+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise ()
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168737+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168737+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1225:10)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168737+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:20)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168738+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/config/mongoose.js:2:10)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168738+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168738+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10) {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168739+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168739+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168739+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(1) {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168740+00:00 app[web.1]: 'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168740+00:00 app[web.1]: _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168741+00:00 app[web.1]: address: 'localhost:27017',
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168741+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'Unknown',
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168741+00:00 app[web.1]: hosts: [],
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168741+00:00 app[web.1]: passives: [],
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168742+00:00 app[web.1]: arbiters: [],
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168742+00:00 app[web.1]: tags: {},
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168742+00:00 app[web.1]: minWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168743+00:00 app[web.1]: maxWireVersion: 0,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168743+00:00 app[web.1]: roundTripTime: -1,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168743+00:00 app[web.1]: lastUpdateTime: 5770712401,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168743+00:00 app[web.1]: lastWriteDate: 0,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168744+00:00 app[web.1]: error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168759+00:00 app[web.1]: at connectionFailureError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:379:20)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket. (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:302:22)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168760+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168760+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168760+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168760+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168761+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168761+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168762+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168762+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168762+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168762+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168762+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168763+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168763+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168764+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168764+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168764+00:00 app[web.1]: code: undefined
2022-08-31T16:44:35.168764+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-31T16:44:35.183629+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server
Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/" host=habittrk.herokuapp.com request_id=84673ff0-3ce9-40eb-a762-f02e05fe7ae1 fwd="47.9.143.69" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22372ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-31T16:44:35.283682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-31T16:44:35.337156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-08-31T16:44:37.523078+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=habittrk.herokuapp.com request_id=fc94e720-483e-4430-9369-ee3fd5d7539d fwd="47.9.143.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: `error connecting to db MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017` I assure you, your database is not at 127.0.0.1 on Heroku. Your app is crashing because you haven't told it where your database is.

Comment: Hi Irfan, next time please give us more context. Explain what it is you are trying to setup and give only the error message. As @ceejayoz stated, you have not correctly configured your MongoDB server. I'm sure this worked with your server locally, but it needs a server that is accessible via the Internet. You can follow either of these guides:

* https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ormongo
* https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/use-atlas-on-heroku/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.